# jQuery - on resize shows bootstrap modal window for every resolution instead of only specific resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When page load if window width >991px fadeIn dropdown form by default, after 4 seconds of delay fadeOut... Question: whether it is recommended to use else statement in this case because practically if if ($(window).width() < 991) .dropdown-menu should not be loaded...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   if ($(window).width() > 991) {
      $(".book.dropdown .dropdown-menu").delay(4000).fadeIn(800).delay(4000).fadeOut(800);
     }
});
```

Second, independently of page load, I want to achieve when is window width > 991px, .book.dropdown should open default dropdown menu which I created, but when is windows width < 991px on click should open JUST bootstrap modal window, but NOT default and modal together.

I want to mention that for the first time after page load, if is windows width > 991px, on click .book.dropdown, dropdown menu opens as expected, when I resize below 991px, on click .book.dropdown, does not open as expected, because opens modal and default dropdown menu (which is defined only for > 991px), when you go back over 991px, modal shows again (problem again).

```js
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  var width = $(window).width(); //check window width
  if (width > 991) {
    $('.book.dropdown, .language.dropdown').on('click', function(e) {
      if (!$(e.target).is('.active_language') && !$(e.target).is('.booking.dropdown-toggle')) {
        return true;
      }

      var $el = $(this),
        $current = $('.navbar').data('popup'),
        visi = function() {
          $('.navbar').data('popup', $el.is(':visible') ? $el : null);
        };
      if ($current != null && !$current.is($el)) {
        $('.dropdown-menu', $current).fadeOut(600);
      }
      $('.dropdown-menu', $el).fadeToggle(600, visi);
    });
  } else {
    $(".book.dropdown").on('click', function(e) {
      $('#book-modal-fullscreen').modal('show');
    });
  };
});
```

I also tried with this code, but I failed to do

```js
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
      var width = $(window).width(); //check window width
  
      ...   
      
     }).resize();
});
```

Also I tried

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      if ($(window).width() > 991) {
        $(".book.dropdown .dropdown-menu").delay(4000).fadeIn(800).delay(4000).fadeOut(800);
      }

      function checkWidth() {
          var width = $(window).width(); //check window width
          if (width < 991) {
            $(".book.dropdown").on('click', function() {
              $('.modal').modal('show');
            });
          } else {
            $('.modal.in').modal('hide');
          }
        }
        // Execute on load
      checkWidth();
      // Bind event listener
      $(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

Comment: it's not necessary to put else statement when the if statement not matched nothing will happen like the way you want it.

Comment: Thanks, can you help me with another issue?

Comment: Ok I am creating fiddle.... JQuery is not included here.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Please paste your solution as answer

Comment: can you tell me what I thought If i got your question correct [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/csb146xL/)

Comment: No, sorry, this is not what I wanted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131442/discussion-between-yonas-hailu-and-mile-mijatovic).

Comment: Please describe the **question** in the title as best as you can. Also please format your question in easier-to-understand paragraphs instead of dumping text and hoping someone will understand

Comment: Ok, I just did it